# Can i use a 3rd party USB C cable to charge a Macbook pro?

Tags: charger

Ive got a 2017 MBP which requires a 87 watt charger.

I use the official apple charger, but can i use any brand USB C cable to connect the charger to the MBP ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use any standards compliant USB-C cable to connect the charger to the MacBook Pro - it doesn't have to be made by Apple.

Note that a standards compliant USB-C cables is only required to be able to carry 60W of power. High-wattage cables are available that can carry up to 100W of power.

In order to get the full output from your charger, you'll want one of the high-wattage cables. However, you won't damage the cable, charger or laptop by using a 60W cable. The charger and laptop will ensure that only 60W of power is actually carried by the cable.